# Should a method always be static if it can be?

Tags: design, object-oriented, web-development, typescript

I am using Typescript in Webstorm with Angular 2 and I am frequently getting warnings that a given method can be static. Yes, these specific methods do not depend on the state of the object they are a part of, but there will not be a time when it is used and the object is not instantiated. Should I still make those methods static?

Comment: [When should I use static methods in a class and what are the benefits?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11240227/102937)

Comment: [What is the gain from declaring a method as static?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11240227/102937)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make methods that do not depend on instance fields, static?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215826/make-methods-that-do-not-depend-on-instance-fields-static)

Answer (score 1):

Don't just make the method static. Make it a function.

Comment: Agreed! The only difference between a static method and a free function is the length of the name. If you really want a long name, then just give your function a long name. Putting it a class is pointless.